# Update Many to Many relationship properties in entity framework core(7) in ASP.Net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have 3 Entity classes like

```
    public class Post {

    [Key]
    public  int PostId { get; set; }
    public  string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }

}


public class Tag {

    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }        
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }

}


public class PostTag {

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }

}
```

These classes are same as entity framework 7 documentation samples and i used OnModelCreating method from the same sample.

While i try to edit post i can't update or modify PostTags.

My edit method in PostsController is like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("PostId,Content,Title")] Post post)
        {
            if (id != post.PostId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                post.PostTags.Clear();
                post.PostTags.Add(new PostTag
                {
                    TagId = 2,
                    PostId = post.PostId
                });
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(post);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PostExists(post.PostId))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(post);
        }
```

I try to clear the previous posttags and add new one. But the new posttag item can't added in database. The previous posttags still exist in DB. That means this method do nothing on posttags property. While adding new post it is working.
Give me solution to add or delete new posttags to post entry while editing Post.

Comment: i think you need to put icollection for post and tag in post tag aswell and it is better to user lisnt instead of icollection and in your db context you need to define the relationship in modelbuilder

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Entity Framework Core:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
            .HasConstraintName("ForeignKey_Post_Blog");
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```